# How to pass a linked list from a file to another in the same project?

Tags: c, list, file, linked-list, project

I am doing a C project that manages the number of rooms in a building, where I can either  choose to reserve or pre-reserve a room.

My problem is that I can't figure out a way of passing a linked list from a file to another.

My main.c looks like this (it's a menu):

```
int main()
{
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    printf("Data: %s\n", ctime(&t));
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    int opcao;
    do{
        printf("\n\tM E N U    P R I N C I P A L\n");
        printf("\n\n\t1 - Ver Reservas Actuais Por Ordem Cronologica");
        printf("\n\n\t2 - Fazer A Sua Reserva");
        printf("\n\n\t3 - Estado Da Sua Reserva");
        printf("\n\n\t4 - Cancelar A Sua Reserva");
        printf("\n\n\t5 - Sair");
        printf("\n\n\n\t\tOpcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        printf("\n");
        fflush(stdin); /*Limpa o Buffer*/

        switch (opcao)
        {
            case 1 : Listar_Fila(FILA Fila); break;
            case 2 : lista_reserva(); break;
            /*case 3 : estado_reserva(); break;
            case 4 : cancelar_reserva(); break;*/
            case 5 : puts("Obrigado por ter preferido o nosso sistema!");break;
            default : puts("OPCAO INVALIDA!!");
        }
        getchar(); /*Para a tela*/
    }
        while (opcao!=5);

}
```

This is how I do my linked list:

```
void lista_reserva()
{


    FILA F;
    char prim_nome_temp[100];
    char ult_nome_temp[100];
    int hora_inic_temp_h , hora_inic_temp_m;
    int hora_fim_temp_h , hora_fim_temp_m;
    int sala_temp;
    inicia_fila(&F);
    puts("Iniciar");
    Listar_Fila(F);
    printf("Inserir Primeiro Nome: ");
    scanf("%s",prim_nome_temp);
    printf("Inserir Ultimo Nome: ");
    scanf("%s",ult_nome_temp);
    printf("Indique que sala pretende reservar: ");
    scanf("%d", &sala_temp);
    printf("Inserir hora de inicio (HH:MM): ");
    scanf("%02d:%02d",&hora_inic_temp_h, &hora_inic_temp_m);
    printf("Inserir hora de fim (HH:MM): ");
    scanf("%02d:%02d",&hora_fim_temp_h , &hora_fim_temp_m);
    insere_fila(&F, sala_temp, hora_inic_temp_h , hora_inic_temp_m , hora_fim_temp_h , hora_fim_temp_m , prim_nome_temp , ult_nome_temp);
    Listar_Fila(F);
}

/* Iniciar uma fila */

void inicia_fila(FILA *Fila)
{
    *Fila = NULL;
}

/*Inserir na Fila */

void insere_fila(FILA *Fila , int sala , int hora_inic_h , int hora_inic_m , int hora_fim_h , int hora_fim_m , char *prim_nome , char *ult_nome)
{
    if (*Fila == NULL)
    {
        *Fila = (FILA) malloc(sizeof(reservas));
        if (*Fila == NULL)
            return;
        ((*Fila)-> sala = sala);
        ((*Fila)-> hora_inic_h = hora_inic_h);
        ((*Fila)-> hora_inic_m = hora_inic_m);
        ((*Fila)-> hora_fim_h = hora_fim_h);
        ((*Fila)-> hora_fim_m = hora_fim_m);
        strcpy((*Fila)-> prim_nome , prim_nome);
        strcpy((*Fila)-> ult_nome , ult_nome);

        (**Fila).proximo = NULL;
    }

    else
        insere_fila(&(**Fila).proximo , sala , hora_inic_h , hora_inic_m , hora_fim_h , hora_fim_m , prim_nome , ult_nome );

}
```

And this is how I print it:

```
void Listar_Fila(FILA Fila)
{
    if (Fila == NULL)
        return; /*Não existem elementos*/
    printf("Sala %d das %d:%d as %d:%d, reservado por %s %s\n\n", Fila -> sala ,Fila ->hora_inic_h , Fila -> hora_inic_m ,Fila -> hora_fim_h , Fila -> hora_fim_m , Fila -> prim_nome , Fila -> ult_nome);
    Listar_Fila(Fila -> proximo);


}
```

I am sorry that my project is not in English and I know it has many beginner mistakes, as I had never worked with C before and I am doing this just has a challenge.

Please, help me improve with any constructive criticism.

Thanks

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior and may cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this is do create the linked list as an "ADT", an [abstact data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type). It consists of a h-file with all the interface functions that main should call, in order to use the linked list. The functions are defined in the corresponding c-file. Simplified example:

```
// list.h
typedef struct
{
  // whatever data you want each node to contain
} node_t;

typedef struct
{
  node_t* head;
  node_t* tail; // optional
  int     size; // optional
} list_t


void list_init (list_t* list);

void list_add  (list_t* list, const node_t* node);

void list_remove (list* list, node_t* node);

void list_destroy (list_t* list);
```

And then in `list.c`, the functions are defined.